# Feature selection with "fscaret" in R issue with empty list()

Tags: r, feature-selection, empty-list

I have a data frame that has a lot of factor and numeric variables and I'm trying to use fscaret package for feature selection.

Sample of the data:

```
age clerical construc educ earns74 gdhlth inlf leis1 rlxal
32  0         0       12   0        0      1   3529  3479
40  1         0       14   9500     1      1   3929  3329
20  1         1       10   329      0      0   5300  2309
22  0         0       6    602      1      0   5205  4290
```

I try to run the following code:

```
 fsMod <- c("gbm", "treebag", "ridge", "lasso", "Boruta", "glm")
myFS<-fscaret(train.sleepDF, test.sleepDF, myTimeLimit = 40, preprocessData=TRUE, Used.funcRegPred = 'fsMod', with.labels=TRUE,
              supress.output=FALSE, no.cores=2)
```

And then finding the `myFS$VarImp` I get `list()`

I've read the annotation to the package and they also report on that issue, not giving a clear solution to it. There appears to be a troublesome method in the calculations, however, how do I identificate it?

Is there a way to solve the problem?
Any help is greatly appreciated.